# Post several duplicated forms, with different info to a new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to create a system to print information about items in a database. By now I have an html form with several input fields (types = text and radio), so I can collect all the info of an item.

To make the process faster I introduce a javascript to duplicate the whole empty form 'n' times with a click, so one can print several items information at once. My script looks like this:

```
<body>
  <button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">add form</button><!--this button duplicates the empty form-->

  <form action="action.php" method="post" name="formulario">

  <div id="duplicater">
<p>Código:<input type="text" name="codigo" /></p>
    <p>Nombre del proyecto:<input type="text" name="proyecto" /></p>

  <p>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="SD" />SD
      <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="HD" />HD
    </span> 
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="4:3"/>4:3 
      <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="16:9"/>16:9
    </span>
  </p>
  <p>Fecha:<input type="text" name="fecha" /></p>
  <p>Lugar:<input type="text" name="lugar" /></p>
  <p>Dueño:<input type="text" name="dueno" /></p>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar" /></p>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicator" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
</body>
```

At this point, this part of the project is working fine, but I have a problem with the action.php file that handle the functionality to send the information from all the forms to a new page to print it.

The action.php collects the information of the form using the name attribute of every input. As every form is just a duplicate of the original one, every new form have the same name attribute, so when I click the send button, the php just echo the information of the last form.

```
<div><span>Código: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['codigo']); ?></div>
<div><span>Proyecto: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['proyecto']); ?></div> 
<div><span>Calidad: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['grupo1']); ?></div>
<div><span>Formato: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['grupo2']); ?></div>
<div><span>Fecha: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fecha']); ?></div>
<div><span>Lugar: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['lugar']); ?></div>
<div><span>Dueño: </span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['dueno']); ?></div>
```

Questions:

I need to update (rename) the name attribute of the input tags in every duplicated form, how can I do that?

It is possible to refer the echo function in the action.php file to a div with an id assigned to post the whole information at once? otherwise, how can I send (post) the information of all the duplicated form to a new page at once?

This have to be a client side process, so there is nothing more behind it, the php is just for echoing the info to the new page. So if there are solutions that can be done with javascript or jQuery is ok as well.

I leave a link to the demo http://www.programaicat.una.ac.cr/ICATsite/demo/

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way POST vars are sent to a script, they're named key, value pairs in an array. Any inputs with the same name will be overwritten.

I suggest appending or prepending a number to each additional input as they are created, so instead of a new input called "name", it would be called "name.1" or "1.name". Your first input would be "name.0" and the rest would increment upwards as they are added. When you process the information, you can iterate over the POST array keys using substr and re-shape your information as needed before saving it to the database.